# Powershell and Winforms controls

Tags: winforms, powershell

If **$form.Controls** returns a list of all the controls on the form, what is the syntax to return a specific control? I want to get a list of all the textboxes on my form, not every control that's on the form. Thanks!

Comment: Where is your [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the items in the `Controls` control collection with `Where-Object`:

```
$TextBoxes = $form.Controls |Where-Object {$_ -is [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]}
```

Comment: Perfect! Is there a way to show the name of the $textbox?

Comment: Nm, found it:-)